# typedef struct, circular dependency, forward definitions

Tags: c, struct, typedef, forward-declaration, circular-dependency

The problem I have is a circular dependency issue in C header files ...Having looked around I suspect the solution will have something to do with Forward Definitions, but although there are many similar problems listed, none seem to offer the information I require to resolve this one...

I have the following 5 source files:

```
// fwd1.h
#ifndef __FWD1_H
#define __FWD1_H

#include "fwd2.h"

typedef
  struct Fwd1 {
    Fwd2  *f;
 }
Fwd1;

void  fwd1 (Fwd1 *f1,  Fwd2 *f2) ;

#endif // __FWD1_H
```

.

```
// fwd1.c
#include "fwd1.h"
#include "fwd2.h"
void  fwd1 (Fwd1 *f1,  Fwd2 *f2)  { return; }
```

.

```
// fwd2.h
#ifndef __FWD2_H
#define __FWD2_H

#include "fwd1.h"

typedef
  struct Fwd2 {
    Fwd1  *f;
  }
Fwd2;

void  fwd2 (Fwd1 *f1,  Fwd2 *f2) ;

#endif // __FWD2_H
```

.

```
// fwd2.c
#include "fwd1.h"
#include "fwd2.h"
void  fwd2 (Fwd1 *f1,  Fwd2 *f2)  { return; }
```

.

```
// fwdMain.c
#include "fwd1.h"
#include "fwd2.h"
int  main (int argc, char** argv, char** env)
{
  Fwd1  *f1 = (Fwd1*)0;
  Fwd2  *f2 = (Fwd2*)0;

  fwd1(f1, f2);
  fwd2(f1, f2);

  return 0;
}
```

Which I am compiling with the command: `gcc fwdMain.c fwd1.c fwd2.c -o fwd -Wall`

I have tried several ideas to resolve the compile errors, but have only managed to replace the errors with other errors ...How do I resolve the circular dependency issue with the least changes to my code? ...Ideally, as a matter of coding style, I would like to avoid putting the word "struct" all over my code.

Comment: Circular dependency is often a bad idea. Could you merge Fwd1 and Fwd2 into one structure? like 'struct Fw {Fw *f1; Fw **f2;}' ? Another thing you haven't initialised 'f1' and 'f2' in your 'main()'.

Comment: @BlueChip Please if an answer solves your inconvenient, then mark it as correct so others with a similar inconvenient will know it is a solution.

Comment: @Thanushan Balakrishnan : As you can imagine, the _actual_ problem is considerably more complex than this simplified example. Sadly combining the elements is not a (reasonable) option ...@cgledezma - I seem to have my email options set wrongly as I was not informed of solution having been posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that when you do circular types, then on the first compiler run, gcc won't have the full type definitions (that's why you get the error of undefined structures and stuff), so on the appropriate places it is necessary to place the word 'struct' before the proper names. So your declarations should look something like this:

fwd1.h:

```
//fwd1.h
#ifndef __FWD1_H
#define __FWD1_H

#include "fwd2.h"

typedef struct Fwd1{
    struct Fwd2  *f;
}Fwd1;


void  fwd1 (Fwd1 *f1,  struct Fwd2 *f2) ;

#endif // __FWD1_H
```

fwd2.h:

```
// fwd2.h
#ifndef __FWD2_H
#define __FWD2_H

#include "fwd1.h"

typedef struct Fwd2{
  struct Fwd1  *f;
}Fwd2;

void  fwd2 (struct Fwd1 *f1,  Fwd2 *f2) ;

#endif // __FWD2_H
```

Perform the equivalent changes on the function definitions on the .c. It should work like a charm.

P.S: The purpose of a .h file is to declare all the headers, i.e: function definitions, includes, etc. that your .c will need. So no need to repeat any includes on the .c apart from the one of the respective .h.

That means your fwd1.c should only include fwd1.h, and then all the other includes should be placed on fwd1.h.

Comment: Another solution is to just throw in another 'typedef struct Fwd2 Fwd2" in fwd1.h and 'typedef struct Fwd1 Fwd1' in fwd2.h.

Comment: Or.. you could put the struct declaration above the #include in each header.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to test this but I think that the following variant is likely to work.

```
// fwd1.h
#ifndef __FWD1_H
#define __FWD1_H

struct Fwd2; // use forward declaration of Fwd2 structure

typedef
  struct Fwd1 {
    Fwd2  *f;
 }
Fwd1;

void  fwd1 (Fwd1 *f1,  Fwd2 *f2) ;

#endif // __FWD1_H

// fwd1.c is without changes

// fwd2.h
#ifndef __FWD2_H
#define __FWD2_H

struct Fwd1; // the same trick

typedef
  struct Fwd2 {
    Fwd1  *f;
  }
Fwd2;

void  fwd2 (Fwd1 *f1,  Fwd2 *f2) ;

#endif // __FWD2_H

// fwd2.c is without changes

// fwdMain.c is without changes
```

Comment: This would work in C++, but in C a `struct` tag is not a type (unless you `typedef` it to the same name).

Answer (score 0):

Just add near the top of fwd1.h:

```
typedef struct Fwd2 Fwd2;
```

Now you can use `Fwd2` as an incomplete type, for example to declare `Fwd2*` pointers.  Similarly, in fwd2.h you would want:

```
typedef struct Fwd1 Fwd1;
```

fwd1.h and fwd2.h don't even need to `#include` each other.

Comment: @aschelper : I was taken by such an elegant solution, but sadly `main.c` fails to compile when using this method as it is _required_ to include both headers (for the function prototypes) and the redefinition of the `typedef`s makes the compiler belch

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of providing a complete working example of circularly-dependent typedef structs:

```
$ cat a.h
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__
typedef struct b_t b_t;
typedef struct a_t {
  b_t * b;
} a_t;
#endif //__A_H__

$ cat b.h
#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__
typedef struct a_t a_t;
typedef struct b_t {
  struct a_t * a;
} b_t;
#endif //__B_H__

$ cat main.c
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  a_t a;
  b_t b;
  a.b = NULL;
  b.a = NULL;
  printf("Done.\n");
  return 0;
}

$ cat Makefile
all: main.c a.h b.h
        gcc main.c -o main

clean:
        rm main

$ make
gcc main.c -o main

$ ./a.out
Done.

$
```